# CIE XY chromaticities into CCT and back

Tags: swift, colors, color-space, cct

I'm trying to convert CIE XY chromaticity coordinates 1931 2deg color space into CCT and back. I followed linked formulas.

[McCamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_color_temperature#Approximation) function:

```swift
func xyToCCT(x: Double, y: Double) -> Int {
    let n = (x - 0.3320) / (y - 0.1858)
    return Int( (-449 * pow(n, 3)) + (3525 * pow(n, 2)) - (6823.3 * n) + 5520.33 )
}

// TEST RESULTS
print(xyToCCT(x: 0.44758, y: 0.40745)) // A   2857.13110 round to 2857 instead 2856
print(xyToCCT(x: 0.34567, y: 0.35850)) // D50 5002.09743 round to 5002 instead 5003
print(xyToCCT(x: 0.31271, y: 0.32902)) // D65 6504.38938 round to 6504 correct 6504
print(xyToCCT(x: 0.31379, y: 0.34531)) // F5  6345.90175 round to 6346 instead 6350
```

[Kang 2002](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/temperature/kang2002.py#L116) function:

```swift
func cctToXY(k: Int) -> (x: Double, y: Double)? {
    let k = k
    
    guard k > 1667 && k < 25000 else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let cct_3 = pow(Double(k), 3)
    let cct_2 = pow(Double(k), 2)
    
    var x: Double {
        if k <= 4000 {
            return -0.2661239 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 - 0.2343589 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.8776956 * pow(10, 3) / Double(k) + 0.17991
        } else {
            return -3.0258469 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 + 2.1070379 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.2226347 * pow(10, 3) / Double(k) + 0.24039
        }
    }
    
    let x_3 = pow(x, 3)
    let x_2 = pow(x, 2)
    
    var y: Double {
        if k <= 2222 {
            return -1.1063814 * x_3 - 1.34811020 * x_2 + 2.18555832 * x - 0.20219683
        } else if k <= 4000 {
            return -0.9549476 * x_3 - 1.37418593 * x_2 + 2.09137015 * x - 0.16748867
        } else {
            return 3.0817580 * x_3 - 5.8733867 * x_2 + 3.75112997 * x - 0.37001483
        }
    }
    
    return (x: x, y: y)
}

// TEST RESULTS
print(cctToXY(k: 2856)!) //   x: 0.4470706750966438 y: 0.40750879834778053
                         // A x: 0.44758            y: 0.40745

print(cctToXY(k: 5003)!) //     x: 0.3449074537491241 y: 0.35151935324713224
                         // D50 x: 0.34567            y: 0.35850

print(cctToXY(k: 6504)!) //     x: 0.313432036002229 y: 0.323601871509382
                         // D65 x: 0.31271           y: 0.32902

print(cctToXY(k: 6350)!) //    x: 0.3158877226651461 y: 0.3259845718669351
                         // F5 x: 0.31379            y: 0.34531
```

My source for coordinates and CCT - [Wikipedia Standard Illuminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#White_points_of_standard_illuminants).

Ideas about why results are incorrect? Maybe rounding errors in the official values?
I haven't found an official CIE table that can refer for more precise coordinates or the same with more decimals.

Then, exist equivalent formulas for CIE XY chromaticity coordinates 1964 10deg?

Comment: Those two functions are only approximations, Roberston (1968) and Ohno (2013) are much more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, there are a couple of different notions of CCT that are commonly used:

- CCT calculated according to the smooth spectral power distribution of an "ideal" [blackbody radiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)
- CCT calculated according to the uneven spectral power distribution of daylight ([illuminant series D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#Illuminant_series_D))

For blackbody calculations, xy chromaticity can be [calculated precisely using an observer's colour matching functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus#The_Planckian_locus_in_the_XYZ_color_space), whereas standard illuminant D provides its [own definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#Computation).

e.g. CCT 6504 K of...

- blackbody with 1931 2 degree observer = `(0.313465, 0.323569)`
- blackbody with 1964 10 degree observer = `(0.313895, 0.324473)`
- daylight according to CIE illuminant D = `(0.312714, 0.329119)`

Note that:

- "6504" is usually shorthand for "6500 * 1.4388 / 1.4380" due to constant c2 [being revised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus#International_Temperature_Scale), which gives CIE illuminant D CCT of `(0.312720, 0.329125)`
- I believe the white point of `(0.31272, 0.32903)` listed on Wikipedia is calculated according to `XYZ -> xyY` conversion formula, not `CCT -> xy` using spectral power distribution equations.

This is all to say: half the battle is knowing which values you are actually trying to match.

With [my own library](https://github.com/waacton/Unicolour) I've found [this approach](https://doi.org/10.1080/15502724.2014.839020), Ohno (2013), produces accurate roundtrip conversions between xy chromaticity and CCT & Duv (within 1 K CCT and -0.03 to 0.03 Duv for values between 1,000 K - 20,000 K).

Comment: I took time to delve deeper into your answer and library, great work! Working with ICC profiles my case falls into the spectral power of daylight (*also for illuminants A, C and F series?*).
I fell down the rabbit hole of trying to name the xyz white point coordinates of a `.icc` starting from xy (2deg) or CCT.

Comment: I'm glad it helps, I spent a while trying to wrap my head around this recently too. In particular I've been frustrated by the lack of agreement on what value a white point represents (and there is an interesting discussion here: https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/well-behaved-profiles-quest.html#white-point-values)